# Clarification on the words timeslice and spaceslice

Tags: spacetime, terminology, definition

I just want some clarification what the words timeslice and spaceslice mean. In so many books and papers in higher-level physics the say something like "at a constant timeslice". Does this simply mean "at a constant time"? Isn't adding "slice" at the end just redundant?

I understand that the word slice can make sense because one can think about a constant time/space in a space-time diagram as a slice in the plane. But still I don't see how it differs from just "constant time/space"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the key things to note is that from a relativistic perspective, time is *local*. That is, when we label an event with its spatial coordinates and the time at which it occurs, that time must be understood as being measured by a clock which is sitting at those spatial coordinates. For example:

> A firecracker exploded at position $(x,y,z)$ and time $t$ **as measured by the clock at $(x,y,z)$.**

Once we adopt this perspective, we see immediately that all of the different (imaginary) clocks ticking away at all of the different spatial positions need to be synchronized with one another before we can make sense of any experiment which doesn't occur in one single location.

Imagine walking through a clock shop in which all the clocks were set to random times.  Let clocks $A$ and $B$ be at positions $x_A$ and $x_B$.  When you walk past clock $A$, it reads time $t_A$, and when you walk past clock $B$ it reads time $t_B$.  Therefore, we define your average velocity to be $v_{AB} := \frac{x_B-x_A}{t_B-t_A}$. You should see that if the clocks in the shop are not all synchronized, this number is effectively meaningless - or at the very least, does not reflect what you would ordinarily think of as velocity.

To fix this, you might carry a watch on your wrist and, as you walk around the shop very slowly, adjust each clock to match your wristwatch. *Now* the aforementioned velocity measurement makes sense to you.  This ends up being equivalent to the [Einstein synchronization convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation) (in the limit of vanishing walking speed).

The great insight of special relativity is that if the clocks in the shop are synchronized by the shop owner, then an observer moving at relativistic speed past the shop would *not* observe them to be synchronized.  Instead, she would observe the clocks on one side of the shop to be ahead of the clocks on the other side of the shop.

More abstractly, we could decide on a nearly arbitrary system of synchronization where, from the perspective of the shop owner walking around the shop, there is a continuous variation with the clocks in one area being slightly ahead or behind the clocks in another area.  The only condition we must impose for self-consistency is that if a signal is sent from clock $A$ at local time $t_A$ and received at clock $B$ at local time $t_B$, then $t_B>t_A$.

---

With those preliminary remarks out of the way, we might define a time slice $\Sigma_T$ as a set of events such that there exists a coordinate system $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ where

$$\Sigma_T := \{(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)\in \mathbb R^4 \ | \ x^0 = T\}$$

Extending the clock shop metaphor, $\Sigma_T$ is the set of events in which every clock reads $T$.  Different systems of synchronization (i.e. different choices of time coordinate) yield different time slices; for inertial observers using Cartesian coordinates - such as the shop owner, or the observer driving down the street - time slices are just planes in spacetime. In more general cases, such as those which arise in GR, they can be more general surfaces.

> Does this simply mean "at a constant time"? Isn't adding "slice" at the end just redundant?

Basically, yes. To put it in context, if we were e.g. trying to solve Maxwell's equations, we might say that we need to specify initial conditions on some **time slice**.  This would be equivalent to saying that we need to specify the initial conditions on **some set of events which, in some coordinate system, have the same time coordinate**.  Of course, the latter is quite a bit clunkier to say.

On the other hand, saying that we need to specify the initial conditions **at some time** feels inadequate.  It's nice to have a noun (i.e. "time slice") to describe the subset of spacetime on which I will be specifying my initial conditions.  It's nice to be able to say that two events are simultaneous if they lie on the same time slice; this makes it abundantly clear that simultaneity is almost entirely dependent on how one does their slicing, and is not an intrinsic property of some any distinct pair of events.

Ultimately, what language you use is a matter of personal choice. In my opinion, deciding not to use the term "slice" (or something equivalent to it) will inevitably paint you into a corner in which you are forced either to use vague, misleading language or clunky, awkward phrasing. But as always, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the idea of a slice is helpful because the slice need not be a plane of constant time. Indeed, in SR one of the most fundamental and important concepts to grasp in the relativity of simultaneity, which reflects the fact that a constant time in one frame of reference is a sloping slice through time in another. If you did not use the word slice, then yes the words constant time would serve by themselves if that is what you meant, but you would struggle to articulate a sloping slice through time.